# How to automatically shorting To/Cc/Bcc recipient/Sender to friendly Hyperlink

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-form-region

I want to when every Reply/Forward an email in Outlook 365 that the last To/Cc are shorten to Friendly Hyper Link like this:
[Explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohC70.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for pasting hyperlinks into these fields in the Outlook UI. The best what you can do is to replace the inspector UI with a form region, see [How to create replacement or replace-all outlook form regions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/0e56d3ec-2037-4361-9d4c-6f911b555981/how-to-create-replacement-or-replaceall-outlook-form-regions?forum=vsto) for more information on that.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, When I looked at some email system in China mainland, they can customize like this so I was wonder.

If so do you Outlook possible to not include Email address - Only include Full Name/Title of Receipient/Sender?

Comment: The name is displayed in Outlook if the recipient's email address is listed in the address book.